# A generalization of $p$-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

I was wondering if there is a reference studying  groups with order $m^k$ where $m,k$ are integers and $m$ is not supposed to be a prime, as a generalization of $p$-groups?

Comment: I guess the right generalization would be to study classes of finite groups in the generated by a group variety under taking extensions. A closer case would be to consider all groups with prime divisors in some given finite set, e.g., all groups of order *dividing* $6^n$ for some $n$. Indeed the class you're suggesting is not stable under taking subgroups/quotients when $m$ is not a prime power.

Comment: Seems unlikely to admit a fairly general approach, because you'd be studying all groups of order $m$ of necessity (as your class would include the groups $G^k$ for any $|G|=m$), and that can get very ad hoc and complex if $m$ isn't very nice.  And just about every property that makes $p$-groups study-able in (more-or-less) their entirety are all dependent on the primality.  Are there particular things you're hoping to know about such groups?

Comment: An example of a reference is Burnside's $p^aq^b$ Theorem ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_theorem)).

Comment: A better generalization is given by finite nilpotent groups. Every finite $p$-group is nilpotent and by a well- known theorem, each finite nilpotent group is  isomorphic to the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.